# Use LINQ to get specific list from within a table

Tags: c#, linq

In my employee table each employee has an EmployeeId and a SupervisorId.  I have five tiers of employees: employees, supervisors, managers, deputy directors, and the main director.  The SupervisorId of the main director is also their EmployeeId (their own boss, so to speak).

I want a C# method that uses LINQ - passing in an EmployeeId to find all underlings for the given employee.  Example:  I pass in the EmployeeId of a deputy director - I want to get back all managers that are assigned to that deputy director (multiple managers have their SupervisorId as the EmployeeID of the deputy director), and then the supervisors under those managers, and then the employees under those supervisors.

I'm able to get back anyone that is a supervisor, manager, deputy director, or the main director with this code:

```
        //Get all active employees
        var activeEmployeeList = _context.Employees
            .Where(e => e.TerminationDate == null)
            .OrderBy(e => e.LastName).ThenBy(e => e.FirstName)
            .ToList();

        //Get all Supervisors, Managers, and Directors
        var supervisors = activeEmployeeList
            .Join(activeEmployeeList, e1 => e1.EmployeeId, e2 => e2.SupervisorId, (e1, e2) => new { e1, e2 })
            .Select(te => new
            {
                Id = te.e2.SupervisorId,
                SupervisorId = te.e1.SupervisorId,
                Value = te.e1.LastName + ", " + te.e1.FirstName
            }).Distinct().OrderBy(te => te.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: C# is a language of types - what type do you expect to be returned? What does "and then" mean in data structure terms?

Comment: I want to return a type of List<Employee>.  When I say "and then" I mean "also include in the List<Employee>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if `activeEmployeeList` is a `List<Employee>` for all employees company wide, would the following solve your issue?

```
List<Employee> GetUnderlings(int superiorId) 
=> activeEmployeeList.Where(x => x.SupervisorId == superiorId)
    .Concat(
        activeEmployeeList.Where(x => x.SupervisorId == superiorId)
        .SelectMany(y => GetUnderlings(y.EmployeeId))
    ).ToList();
```

This would be more efficient if you drop the `.ToList()` and just return an `IEnumerable<Employee>`, calling `.ToList()` when you invoke the method.

Also, just a matter of personal preference, but don't call variables that hold lists "...List", just pluralise them. (`activeEmployees`). Its a bit too close to Hungarian notation and if you go down the road of refactoring to `IEnumerable`s, you won't need to rename them.

Comment: This worked great, and is a LOT less code then what I had.  Many thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working in SQL code:

```
USE [Employee_Prod]

DECLARE @pstrEmployeeId VARCHAR(9)
SET @pstrEmployeeId = '3534'

;WITH cte1 AS
(
    SELECT 
        EmployeeID,
        LastName + ', ' + FirstName AS EmployeeName,
        SupervisorID
    FROM Employee
    WHERE SupervisorID = @pstrEmployeeId 
    AND TermDate IS NULL
)
, cte2 AS
(
    SELECT 
        e.EmployeeID,
        e.LastName + ', ' + e.FirstName AS EmployeeName,
        e.SupervisorID
    FROM Employee e
    INNER JOIN cte1 a ON a.EmployeeID = e.SupervisorID
    WHERE e.TermDate IS NULL
)
, cte3 AS
(
    SELECT 
        e.EmployeeID,
        e.LastName + ', ' + e.FirstName AS EmployeeName,
        e.SupervisorID
    FROM Employee e
    INNER JOIN cte2 b ON b.EmployeeID = e.SupervisorID
    WHERE e.TermDate IS NULL
)
, cte4 AS
(
    SELECT 
        e.EmployeeID,
        e.LastName + ', ' + e.FirstName AS EmployeeName,
        e.SupervisorID
    FROM Employee e
    INNER JOIN cte3 c ON c.EmployeeID = e.SupervisorID
    WHERE e.TermDate IS NULL
)

SELECT * FROM cte1
UNION
SELECT * FROM cte2
UNION
SELECT * FROM cte3
UNION
SELECT * FROM cte4
ORDER BY EmployeeName
```

I then turned to ChatGPT to have the code converted to LINQ.  I have this working in my C# code:

```
var cte1 = _context.TblEmployees
                .Where(employee => employee.SupervisorId == id && employee.TermDate == null)
                .Select(employee => new EmployeeDTO
                {
                    EmployeeId = employee.EmployeeId,
                    EmployeeName = employee.LastName + ", " + employee.FirstName,
                    SupervisorId = employee.SupervisorId,
                    TermDate = employee.TermDate
                }).Distinct();

            var cte2 = _context.TblEmployees
                .Join(cte1, employee => employee.SupervisorId, a => a.EmployeeId, (employee, a) => new EmployeeDTO
                {
                    EmployeeId = employee.EmployeeId,
                    EmployeeName = employee.LastName + ", " + employee.FirstName,
                    SupervisorId = employee.SupervisorId,
                    TermDate = employee.TermDate
                })
                .Where(employee => employee.TermDate == null);

            var cte3 = _context.TblEmployees
                .Join(cte2, employee => employee.SupervisorId, b => b.EmployeeId, (employee, b) => new EmployeeDTO
                {
                    EmployeeId = employee.EmployeeId,
                    EmployeeName = employee.LastName + ", " + employee.FirstName,
                    SupervisorId = employee.SupervisorId,
                    TermDate = employee.TermDate
                })
                .Where(employee => employee.TermDate == null);

            var cte4 = _context.TblEmployees
                .Join(cte3, employee => employee.SupervisorId, c => c.EmployeeId, (employee, c) => new EmployeeDTO
                {
                    EmployeeId = employee.EmployeeId,
                    EmployeeName = employee.LastName + ", " + employee.FirstName,
                    SupervisorId = employee.SupervisorId,
                    TermDate = employee.TermDate
                })
                .Where(employee => employee.TermDate == null);

            var underlings = cte1.Concat(cte2).Concat(cte3).Concat(cte4).OrderBy(e => e.EmployeeName).ToList();

            var result = underlings.DistinctBy(e => e.EmployeeId).ToList();

            return result;
```

I created a model class for a shortened version of my Employee class:

```
public class EmployeeDTO
{
    public string? EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string? EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string? SupervisorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TermDate { get; set; }        
}
```

I'm sure this can be shortened and greatly improved upon.  I have it working, so I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Did you try my answer?